# MFC with active links or buttons as background in mainframe

Tags: button, hyperlink, background, mfc, mdi

I'm able to change the background of my MFC MDI application's mainframe, but I'm wondering if it's possible to add links or buttons to the background? Similar to what's possible with HTML Images and multiple links and create the effect of having tiles.

Comment: Can you explain further?  Are you asking to add controls to the actual frame window?  A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Similar to http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/ but using MFC and linking to functions in the application.

Comment: I took a look at that page, but, I'm still not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish.  It looks like you're trying to setup a hyperlink from an image, but, I'm not sure if that's correct, or, how you want it to fit into the context of your application.

Comment: Instead of hyperlinks, it will be buttons or functions. One background where you can click to activate functions like you would if it was a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the same thing (which you [referred](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/)) in MFC, you can do it by tracking the position of mouse pointer, but you can't create a button or link on the background. To track follow the step,

1. Get the co-ordinates of the each logo and store it in individual
   [`CRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h58f4c7y.aspx) objects (as explained in the reference example).
2. Listen to one of `ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN` or `ON_WM_LBUTTONUP` message and track the mouse click event on [`OnLButtonDown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c293as9k.aspx) or [`OnLButtonUp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k72b8d0t.aspx) function accordingly.
3. When the function is called, check whether the `CPoint` is inside the `CRect` using [`PtInRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebs091e.aspx) function.
4. If the point lies inside any of the `CRect` objects the perform the operations accordingly.

**NOTE:** Even it is possible to change the mouse pointer on hover the logo by listening to `ON_WM_SETCURSOR` message.